# LinearGradient on TabItem in TabView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to apply a LinearGradient to a TabItem? AccentColor only takes a color, and I haven't found another way to apply any color to a TabItem.
Any Ideas?[image: This in a Gradient from Blue to Green for example]
(This in a Gradient from blue to green, for example)

Comment: Could you show some demo, like screenshot, mockup, etc. of what do you try to achieve?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509167/how-to-apply-gradient-to-an-accentcolor-of-any-view-swiftui

Comment: @koen since SwiftUI only show no more than one Image and Text view , we cannot use mask with Gradient.

Comment: @Yodagama thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no chance to apply gradient in SwiftUI for the accentColor. So in your case you will have to create your own Tab Bar Items Images with a gradient and save them as a png. You will have to match the sizes, as you can not resize `Image` inside tabItem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874619/11878069) answer for the sizes

You will need an active Image with your gradient and a inactive Image maybe gray like the default TabBar behavior. Then just load your Images in the TabView and depending on the selection..

Here is an example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("First")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(selection == 0 ? "home_active" : "home_inactive") //<< here you load your different images 

                    Text("Home")
                        .colorMultiply(Color.yellow)
                }

            Text("Second")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(selection == 1 ? "setting_active" : "setting_inactive")
                    Text("Setting")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes we cannot apply gradient on tabItem in SwiftUI. It only shows no more than one Image and one Text view, although we have put more views inside .tabItem{}.

So that you have to make custom tab bar.